# A simple (clone only) Mercurial client in pure Java?

Tags: java, mercurial, client

There are somewhat recurring questions about whether there's a pure Java Mercurial client available (or whether is it possible to run Mercurial in a Javafied Python environment, such as Jython. Googling around, nothing recent is found and it seems that Jython is not able to support Mercurial on the whole.

But I have a tightly focused requirement: to only perform an hg clone (from scratch). Maybe this relaxed constraint makes it possible to solve the problem. Does anybody knows about it?

My problem is that the operation must be performed from a webapp running in a virtualized host where there's no hg support. I have other choices (such as downloading the files by browsing the web access that most forces offer), but of course a direct integration would be preferred.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use static-http or ssh as transport for the source repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [Hg4J](http://hg.hg4j.com/). Their most recent version 0.1.0 (as of July 21) doesn't seem to support clone, but it seems possible according to their [sources](http://hg.hg4j.com/hg4j/file/0e01f9182e16/src/org/tmatesoft/hg/core/HgCloneCommand.java). So maybe try an unofficial build.

Personally I would too go with downloading an archive that hgweb offers.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say that I need an Apache-friendly FLOSS license, and unfortunately Hg4J is GPL v2. Even though I could launch it in a separate process (which would make ASF v2 and GPL v2 to co-exist)...